# How to connect ALM (QC)with selenium web driver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, alm, hp-quality-center

Please suggest me steps to connect with ALM by selenium web driver.

Assignment :

1. Create connection with ALM by selenium web driver.
   2.Mark Test cases as Pass / Fail

Answer (score 1):

For ALM I would suggest using the REST API as this works OS independent while OTA only works on windows with installem ALM client.

For the other part it depends which testing framework you use.
For Java with TestNG you can create a simple listener and act correspondingly on failed and passed tests events to update the status.

Answer (score 0):

ALM and WebDriver are two different tools..

You may need to connect with ALM by OTA API or REST API..

You may need to choose any programming language which supports COM objects if you plane for OTA API... know thing is VB Script one of the very handy scripting language..

Just try by google and check how to interact with ALM by using language which you are using in selenium automation.. will give you good idea.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I recently found that ALM and Webdriver can be integrated using JACOB Project(ALM Service Wrapper)

Note : Ensure Jacob 32 bit dll is added to your classpath and Jacob.jar is referenced to your automation project

Here is the link where you can find the whole JACOB Project(dll and jar) :

http://automationtestingutilities.blogspot.in/2013/12/IntegrationWithQCorALMusingALMServiceWrapperPart2.html

Read their doc for more information on Jacob Project